# State transition controlled by Effort value

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I need to check if the value of the effort field is greater than 5. If this condition is true the item has to be approved, so in that case the next state has to be another than if the effort is less or equal 5.
Is there any opportunity to set this condition?

Comment: Can't be done
<TD;DR>

There is no such rule and since field Effort is a double typed field, it's not possible to use a list of allowedvalues (which would have worked for an integer field). Tools like the TFS Aggregator won't help either, as they can only act post-changed, there is no pre-validation support for Work Item changes on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done

### `<TD;DR>`

There is no such rule and since field Effort is a double typed field, it's not possible to use a list of allowedvalues (which would have worked for an integer field). Tools like the TFS Aggregator won't help either, as they can only act post-changed, there is no pre-validation support for Work Item changes on the server side.